# Android protect mp3 file form being shared, but still playable

Tags: android, mp3, copy-protection

how can I protect an mp3 file I downloaded from my server (legal content owner) from being forwarded via email, Bluetooth etc.

I wish the file be playable on device media player so i will send it to ContentResolver.

I have seen this on some official apps for our region, but i do not know how to flag/mark my files as non share-able.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

> how can I protect an mp3 file I downloaded from my server (legal content owner) from being forwarded via email, Bluetooth etc.

Technically, you can't, unless you implement your own MP3 player app and store it in there. If you are relying upon other apps to play the music, then by definition other apps have access to the music and could conceivably do things with it, such as sharing it via email, Bluetooth, etc.

However, in practice, if you are the one starting up the media player to play your music, and you do not offer options for sharing via email, Bluetooth, etc., then the user is unlikely to have any convenient means to do so themselves, except on rooted devices.

Comment: Sure, I was thinking on using contentprovider for allowing 3rd party apps to use content from me.
I am not quite sure can this be done.
Would be much more elegant if there is some OS security implementation.